# questionable actionsfor program rwe

Tags: c++, arrays

my prgram is telling me that r cant equal a variable that isnt in the scope but it was in the argument call?

int main(){

int r = 12;

cout << "r";

return r;
}

Answer (score 1):

`int main(int arr[], int n)` is not a valid signature for `main()`, so right off the bat your code has *undefined behavior*. Since you don't use any command-line parameters, use `int main()` instead.

Also, [don't use <bits/stdc++.h>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/).

But, regarding your code logic, when `main()` is calling `insertionSort()` and `printArray()`, it is passing a pointer to the *invalid* `arr` rather than the *populated* vector `array`. But fixing that, `&array[sizeArray]` would be out of bounds of the vector, it needs to be `&array[0]` instead, or better `array.data()`. And `n` does not hold the size of the vector, you need to use `sizeArray` instead, or better `array.size()`.

Try this instead:

```
int main() {
    ...
    insertionSort( array.data(), array.size());
    printArray( array.data(), array.size());
}
```

Comment: Also arr and array are mixed up. Data is read from user and pushed  into array, but then arr is used as parameter for the functions

Comment: @ArminMontigny good catch. I have updated my answer.